# Is there a Python library that would have numpy-like data types

Tags: python, numpy, user-defined-data-types

I'm a C developer that need to access a FTDI device using the pyftdi library and as I try to manipulate the remote registers of the slaves.  I found that it is impossible to execute bitwise operations (bitshift, NOT, AND and OR) on things other than `int` in Python but I found the NumPy library that has data types that enable such functionality.  My problem is that NumPy is very heavy on resources and I wonder if there is an alternative to such a heavy library.

I've tried the native `BitField` of PyFtdi which doesn't have such functionalities and the ctypes library which neither has.

This is the kind of code where I would like not to use NumPy for:

```
def set_bit(variable, bit_ID):
    variable |= np.ubyte(1 << bit_ID)
    return variable
```

Again, the main issue is not that it doesn't work, it is that it works but is very heavy on ressources and I need the functionalities of a 8-bit variables with the bitwise operators without always switching data types.

I need that kind of variable to avoid casting multiple times my variables using pyftdi's functions:
Acquiring data from it in the Python-native `bytes()` and converting it to `int`.
Then using the bitwise operator and restricting to 8 bits the outputs.
Then converting back to `bytes()` to send them back via the I2C API of PYFTDI.

Comment: **I found that it is impossible to execute bitwise operations  on things other than int in python**, with what do you want to do bitwise operations?

Comment: What's wrong with `int` though? Why do you require the function to return a `np.ubyte` instead of a python integer? I'm not sure what your input and required output is, but python integers have no fixed size in memory, like 32 bits, so returning `1 << bit_ID` will always work.

Comment: You might want `bytestrings`, similar to `numpy's` 'Sn' dtype.

Comment: Requesting libraries is explicitly off-topic on StackOverflow. Read [ask]

Comment: @CaptainTrojan, The problem with int is that I always need to do units casting to avoid type error.  Most pyftdi functions uses bytes() which aren't able to do bitwise operation.  So without using np I need to get the value from bytes to int, do the bitwise operations, then convert it back to int, therefore impeding program clarity.

Comment: @hpaulj, I'll try your suggestion, I'll keep you informed!

Comment: @barny I know it may be not the best way to ask a question, but I am unaware of a place to ask such a question.  If you could point me a place to ask it, I would be pleased to ask it there

Comment: @hpaulj, The library you suggested me only seems to work in one way, converting bytes to string which isn't the way I specified, I need to be able to do bitwise operations on them and use them as bytes

Comment: Doing those bit wise operations in Python depends on whether the object class implements the relevant methods, `.__lshift__` etc.  Of the builtin types only `int` appears to implement them.  `bytes` and `bytearray` only implement string and sequence methods.  Searching `PyPi` (which is where I found `pyftdi`) may be your ownly option.

Comment: @LouisRaymond go searching, is the solution - like I say, on SO requests for recommendations of software/libraries are explicitly off-topic as opinion-based, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Also you should be showing you've done some research. I had no problem goggling for _python bytes binary operation_ to get loads of results to examine. Did you do that?

Comment: @barny, "I've tried the native BitField of PyFtid which doesn't have such functionalities and the ctypes library which neither has."

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have resorted to cast each time the data types in one or another data type.  It's not the most elegant answer to such a problem but it'll do for now.  If someone ever has a miracle solution, fell free to post it ;)